# Fisher's exact test in survival analysis

Tags: survival, fishers-exact-test

How to do Fisher's exact test in univariate survival comparison on 2 groups (10 vs 15 patients), small size events ( 5 vs 3) and multiple times to events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fisher’s “exact” test is only for categorical uncensored dependent variables.

Comment: Thank you sir! I wanted to work on by Log-rank test, but according to some books, my results will be invalid because there are several cases with expected values below 5. What should I do?

Comment: You're still mixing regular categorical Y analysis with survival analysis.  I've never seen "5" used in the context of the logrank test.  But there is no reason for the logrank test to exist.  It is just a special case of the Cox proportional hazards regression model.  Use the likelihood ratio $\chi^2$ test within a Cox model framework.